# How to create an anagram that prints an order of string in python using counter?

Tags: python, counter, anagram

I am struggling to create an order of string using counter in python and my program is not printing an order of the given string below.

```
from collections import Counter, defaultdict  
def checking_anagram(keywords):  
    agrms = defaultdict(list)  
    for i in keywords:  
        hist = tuple(Counter(i).items())  
        agrms[hist].append(i)  
    return list(agrms.values())  
keywords = ("eat","tea","tan","ate","nat","bat","bat")  
print(checking_anagram(keywords))
```

Comment: What is an order of string? How can an anagram print anything?

Comment: What is your program printing instead?

Comment: @mkrieger it only prints eat, tea, tan. input strs = ["eat","tea","tan","ate","nat","bat"]

Output: [["bat"],["nat","tan"],["ate","eat","tea"]]

Comment: Why is printing "eat, tea, tan" bad? What should it print instead?

Comment: "eat", "tea", and "ate" are anagrams of each other. And In the output "bat" is printed twice because of the duplication of "bat" in your input

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The only real problem you have is your `hist` line.  I don't know what you were trying to do, but that is wrong.  What you need to do is sort the letters of each word, and use that as your key:

```
from collections import defaultdict  
def checking_anagram(keywords):  
    agrms = defaultdict(list)  
    for word in keywords:  
        s = ''.join(sorted(word))
        agrms[s].append(word)
    return list(agrms.values())  
keywords = ("eat","tea","tan","ate","nat","bat")  
print(checking_anagram(keywords))
```

Output:

```
[['eat', 'tea', 'ate'], ['tan', 'nat'], ['bat', 'bat']]
```

Comment: thanks for clarify the issue i was using hints

Comment: does this run without any issue on your IDE? I am trying to use pycharm to test this solution before was using cloud IDE its giving compile issues

Comment: The output you see there was produced from THAT code running on my computer.  If it's not working for you, then you made a cut-and-paste error.

Comment: yes the code now works on pycharm IDE. quick question if i want to print reverse order of the keywords. How do i apply this on this program?

Comment: What would be the point?  It's returning a set of words.  Order should be unimportant.  You can certainly do `for word in keywords[::-1]:` to process them in reverse order.